# How to check included ID or not?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have ActiveRecord collection and a I want to check my ID in it.

```
@items_user_id = Item.select("DISTINCT user_id").where(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

and I check

```
@items_user_id.include?(params[:id])
```

returned nil

What's wrong?

UPD 1 : What I need - param[:id] contains id of Item. The user can edit the items created by them only. And I want to check whether the item identifier in the identifier pool items user.

Answer (score 0):

**In short**: you are comparing Apples to Oranges.

**Long Answer**:

`@items_user_id = Item.select("DISTINCT user_id").where(:user_id => current_user.id)` this line will return `Array` of `Item` elements.

params[:id] would possibly be `String` or `Integer` so it would not be found in the Array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to collect the ids from the array obtained and then check..

```
@items_user_id.map(&:id).include?(params[:id])
```

Make sure the datatype of ids(string) matches with params[:id]

Answer (score 0):

The select you do executes this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM items WHERE user_id = ?
```

That will yield either nothing, or a single row with just the user_id.

What do you really want?